# How do I retrieve returned value from sql function in Powershell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Hi I am using Powershell script to call a function which returns me table name and I am unable to understand how to retrieve the value. Below is the code that I am using

```
$SqlQuery = "select dbo.abc_import_create_table_for_file('$fileFullName', '$(gc $fileFullName | select -first 1)');"
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd 
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SqlConnection.Close()
```

Comment: `$DataSet` will contain the output values

Comment: Are you sure abc_import_create_table_for_file is a function? User-defined functions can't have side effects such as creating tables.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - thanks I missed it, I am actually trying to create a proc or function that can create a table and then return me the name of the created table. Table name and the columns depend on the supplied parameters.

Comment: If you call a proc that returns the name of the table as a scalar result (i.e. `SELECT @TableName`), you can use `ExecuteScalar` and skip all the data adapter stuff: `$tableName = $SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()`